# Rails get controller action url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an action, and I've defined it in the `routes.rb`

```
resources :statistics, only: [] do
  get 'group_report/:id', to: 'statistics#group_report', as: 'group_report'
end
```

Then in the method in the model, I want to return the full URL.

Thus, I wrote this method

```
root_url + group_report_statistics_path(id)
```

The result is `"http://localhost:3000//statistics/group_report/DHo6qzUzYXw"`

I thought it was a dirty way, and I need to handle the double slash as well.

Does Rails provide some useful method which I can get the full URL of the action directly?

Answer (score 2):

Rails provides path as well as url helpers for all the routes.

So if you use `group_report_statistics_url(id)`, you will get the full URL.

See [Path and URL Helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers) on the Rails guides for detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
File.join(root_url + group_report_statistics_path(id))
```

or

```
 group_report_statistics_url(id)
```